# When i submit from the HTML page I receive the following error: "Error: Table 'searchquery_interfaithmedical_com.Persons' doesn't exist"

Tags: php, html, sql

I am having a bit of difficulty with setting up SQL Queries with PHP.

I have the following php script:

```
    <?php $con = mysql_connect("URL","USERNAME","PASSWORD"); if (!$con)   {   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   }

mysql_select_db("searchquery_interfaithmedical_com", $con);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE Persons ( FirstName varchar(15), LastName varchar(15), Age int )";

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))   {   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());   } echo "1 record added";

mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Persons";

mysql_close($con); ?>
```

What I am looking to do is take the first name, last name and age into the table Persons in searchquery_interfaithmedical_com database. When i submit from the HTML page I receive the following error: "Error: Table 'searchquery_interfaithmedical_com.Persons' doesn't exist".

Isn't the PHP script is already taking care of the creating of TABLE before inserting? How do I correct the issue?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: basic php. you're assigning two different queries to the same variable. insert overwrites create, boom. no create query. your code is basically `$x = 5; $x = 1000;` and expecting $x to be 5. You are also gaping wide open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). an especially bad thing to for what looks to be medical-related code.

Comment: You are never running your first sql statement...

Comment: So how do I create the query which will create the table in the DB and then insert into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the `$sql` variable to create the table before you run it. Try:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Persons ( FirstName varchar(15), LastName varchar(15), Age int )";
mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";
```

To fetch those values from the table you'd do this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons");
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo $results['FirstName'] . ', ' . $results['LastName'] . ', ' . $results['Age'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Wow THANKS Sean that worked like a charm. What if I also wanted to display in the same script whats in the database so far? Please see me edit above.

Answer (score 1):

Your Create Table is not executed in the first place as you have overwritten the query with the insert. Please use the following code to correct the issue and try to avoid usage of same variable again frequently.

```
<?php $con = mysql_connect("URL","USERNAME","PASSWORD"); 
if (!$con)   
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());   
}

mysql_select_db("searchquery_interfaithmedical_com", $con);

$query1 = "CREATE TABLE Persons ( FirstName varchar(15), LastName varchar(15), Age int )";

mysql_query$query1,$con);

$query2="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysql_query($query2,$con))   
{   
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());  
} 
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con); ?>
```